# I want to split textfile into mutilple text files

Tags: java

Hi I have Text file  having some tag based data and i want to split into multiple text files.

Main Text files having data like this:

```
==========110CYL067.txt============
<Entity Text>Cornell<Entity Type>Person
<Entity Text>Donna<Entity Type>Person
<Entity Text>Sherry<Entity Type>Person
<Entity Text>Goodwill<Entity Type>Organization
==========110CYL068.txt============
<Entity Text>Goodwill Industries Foundation<Entity Type>Organization
<Entity Text>Goodwill<Entity Type>Organization
```

NOTE: Over here 110CYL068.txt and 110CYL067.txt are text files.

I want to split this file into 110CYL068.txt and 110CYL067.txt and so on.

This ============ pattern is fixed.Between ============ FileName ============

file name could be anything.does anyone have any insight.

Comment: And what is your problem or what have you done so far?

Comment: The answer is yes: we generally have quite some insight around here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to write codes for you, so you can read the file using a BufferedReader or FileReader. You can create and write to a new File using any file writer whenever you see a line starting with ======= or containing .txt.
If you encounter those close the previous file and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Done ppl way to complicatet just did it fast and dirty.

```
public static List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String pattern = "==========";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    addLines(importFile());

}

private static List<String> importFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\temp\\test.txt"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            lines.add(line.replaceFirst(pattern, ";") + "\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }

    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
    return lines;
}

private static void addLines(List<String> list) throws IOException {
    String FilesString = list.toString();
    System.out.println(FilesString);
    String[] FilesArray = FilesString.split(";");
    for (String string : FilesArray) {
        createFile(string);
    }
}

private static void createFile(String content) throws IOException {

    String[] Lines = content.replaceAll("=", "").split("\n");
    File file = new File("C:\\temp\\" + Lines[0]);
    file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    Lines[0] = null;
    for (String Line : Lines) {

        if (Line != null) {
            writer.append(Line.replace(",", "")+"\n");

        }

    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Also quick and dirty, not using regex. I don't really recommend doing it like this because the `for` loop in `main` is quite confusing and could break, but it might be beneficial to use this for ideas.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class splitFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            List<String> fileRead = readFiles("some.txt");
            for(int i=0; i<fileRead.size(); i++){
                if(fileRead.get(i).charAt(0) == '='){
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(getFileName(fileRead.get(i)), "UTF-8");
                    for(int j=i+1; j<fileRead.size(); j++){
                        if(fileRead.get(j).charAt(0) == '='){
                            break;
                        } else {
                            writer.println(fileRead.get(j));
                        }
                    }
                    writer.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){

        }

    }

    public static String getFileName(String fileLine){
        String[] split = fileLine.split("=");
        for(String e: split){
            if(e.isEmpty()){
                continue;
            } else {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return "No file name found";
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> readFile(String path){
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(path));
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(s.hasNext()){
                list.add(s.next());
            }
            s.close();
            return list;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f){
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    static List<String> readFiles(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            words.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return words;
    }
}
```